How should I project my coordinates to UTM if they encompass multiple UTM zones?
My issue is that I am working on a really extensive dataset and that my tracking data encompass several UTM zones (12 to be specific: 32-33-34-35-36-37-38-39-40-41-42-43).
Snip of my data:
> head(springsub)
  id              DateTime            lat      lon      Altitude Sex Age Tag                 distance     time_interval velocity    velocity_kmh
1 N34234@1BF1A215 2022-03-15 10:42:00 45.50620 12.57837        5   1   6 GPS-GSM_TECHNOSMART      0.00000            NA          NA           NA
2 N34234@1BF1A215 2022-03-16 06:42:00 48.62932 20.51655      274   1   6 GPS-GSM_TECHNOSMART 695286.88086         72000 9.656762234  34.76434404
3 N34234@1BF1A215 2022-03-16 08:42:00 48.62761 20.51720      262   1   6 GPS-GSM_TECHNOSMART    195.38842          7200 0.027137281   0.09769421
4 N34234@1BF1A215 2022-03-16 10:42:00 48.62785 20.51662      271   1   6 GPS-GSM_TECHNOSMART     50.60765          7200 0.007028840   0.02530382
5 N34234@1BF1A215 2022-03-16 12:41:00 48.62737 20.51678      270   1   6 GPS-GSM_TECHNOSMART     54.77180          7140 0.007671121   0.02761603
6 N34234@1BF1A215 2022-03-16 18:42:00 49.30252 20.92450      914   1   6 GPS-GSM_TECHNOSMART  80799.38930         21660 3.730350383  13.42926138
utm_zone
1       33
2       34
3       34
4       34
5       34
6       34

Now many tracking data analysis workflows use Easting and Northing in UTM coordinates instead of longitude and latitude (which is what I have for now).
I tried projecting my tracks in UTM but obviously they get extremely distorted (when projecting around a "central" UTM zone).
# Project to UTM
llcoord <- st_as_sf(springsub[, c("lon", "lat")], coords =
c("lon", "lat"), crs = CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"))
utmcoord <- st_transform(llcoord, crs = CRS("+proj=utm +zone=37
+datum=WGS84")) 

# Add Easting and Northing to data (in km)
data[, c("x", "y")] <- st_coordinates(utmcoord)/1000

What should I do?
Splitting by UTM zones as in Converting latitude and longitude data to UTM with points from multiple UTM zones in R doesn't sound like a good idea considering that each track encompasses several zones and represents an individual movement.
Should I use a Lambert projection or an Equal Earth projection as in Projecting long/lat with multiple UTM zones instead?
Would that mean still using Easting and Norting metric information suitable for (as an example) a Hidden Markov Model analysis?
Thank you

What kind of analysis do you have in mind? Have you already evaluated using geographic coordinates? I.e anything based on sf where you could use spherical geometries (s2),  like move2 & sftrack ?

If I have no other choice I will use spherical geometries, but i would much rather use a HMM. So I am trying to prepare my df to run a HMM analysis defining relevant movement states to grasp overall movement patterns (this is also because I need a quite straightforward way to identify stopover sites over a number of migratory tracks). But before I do any of this I need the coordinates to be in UTM format (or at least some metric projection), otherwise even computing step lengths and turning angles becomes challenging.
